# Error locating iPhone Tracker CellLocation using Windows cmd

Tags: iphone, windows, cmd, geolocation

What is the correct way to write the following code?

I copied it directly from the site, but added my name instead as the user.

What am I doing wrong?

```
findstr /M CellLocation C:UsersDontaeAppDataRoamingApple ComputerMobileSyncBackup[latest backup folder].
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
Findstr cannot open CusersDontaeappData RoamingApple. 
Findstr Cannot open ComputerMobileSyncBackup[latest.
Findstr Cannot open backup 
Findstr Cannot open folder].
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing all of the `\` characters from the `pathname` argument supplied to `findstr`.

Use the following command:

```
findstr /M CellLocation C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\[latest backup folder]\*.*
```

Where *[Username]* and *[latest backup folder]* are the correct values for your system.

If the correct `pathname` contains spaces you may also need to quote `"` the `pathname` argument.

---

Source [iphone tracker](http://andykn.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/iphone-tracker.html)